# Databases in local programming

Tags: ruby, database, oop

I am trying to model cooperation in Ruby, and I have classes like  `Simulator` and `Agent`. I find I will end up doing things that would fit well with databases, like saying things like `this.agent.find_by_id(1).score.increment` or `this.cooperate`, where cooperate passes a value to the Simulator, which then adds some value to the two agents score, and keeps one tally for the agents. Is this possible, or am I just thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Do you want to use a database? Your syntax doesn't drive the need to have a database. Data storage and persistence, random access for fast access, huge amounts of data, all those start to point toward the need for a database. If you want ActiveRecod-like syntax, you can write methods based on AR, without the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord outside of rails:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql2',
  :database => 'database_name',
  :username => 'username',
  :password => 'password',
  :host     => 'localhost'
)
```

You classes should just inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. You can probably also use Mongoid or any other database mapper.